# Apache Camel PGP Embedded or Original filename

Tags: cryptography, apache-camel, bouncycastle, pgp

I have a file lets say test.txt, I encrypt it into mypgpfile.pgp.  Now when I decrypt this using apache camel, it writes the output to mypgpfile.pgp.  Is there a way in Camel to know the embeddedfilename?  I want the output to be written to test.txt instead of mypfpfile.pgp.

The code sample is simple as follows.

```
from("direct:unencrypt")
      .unmarshal().pgp(keyFileNameSec, keyUserid, keyPassword)
```

Is it possible to get the original file name by writing custom code using bouncycastle? Can someone please help with suggestions, since retaining the original file name is an important requirement for us.  Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: I'm not familiar with those tools, but crypto in general doesn't pay attention to the source - one could argue that it could cause a security hole through a known-text or side-channel attack. So unless you track the input filename somehow, the encrypted file would have no tie to it. One straightforward solution I can think of would be to concat the source file name at the beginning or end of the file contents (with a delimiter) before performing the encryption.

Comment: The encrypted files comes from different clients and we don't have control on adding the source file name to the file contents.  Unless there is a way to do that programmatically some way.

Comment: Ah, so you just receive an encrypted file with an obfuscated file name? The only other piece of information you have is the key to decrypt the file?

Comment: Yes Patrick.  That is correct.  To decrypt the file and to retain the original file name is an important requirement, since the processing of the file depends on the name and type of the file.

Comment: If the client renames the file after encryption there is no way to retrieve the original file name. Ask the clients to encrypt the file with the original name. Files do not track i.e. audit their names.

Comment: Using the PGP Desktop tool, I can look at the embedded file name and the file itself.  This tells that the filename is stored somewhere in the encrypted content.  Wondering if there is a way to get a handle to it using the BouncyCastle algorithm or any other way.

Comment: If you want to save the original file name, it might be easier if you zip the file before you encrypt the file.